# How to insert executable name to perror error message?

Tags: c

With the use of `perror`, I have to format the error message.

```
prog: Error: Detailed error message
```

Where `prog` is actually the name of the executable (`argv[0]`) and should be appropriately modified if the name of executable is changed without recompilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a string and then pass that to perror()

```
char err[20];
snprintf(err, sizeof(err), "%s: Error", argv[0]);
perror(err);
```